# Inertiajs - Flashed data stays on the screen for one too many refreshes

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm using InertiaJS for VueJS (3) with Laravel.

I've created the following for flashing data.

```
class SessionFlashMessageRepository implements FlashMessageInterface
{
    public function flashSuccess(string $message)
    {
        session()->flash('success', $message);
    }

    public function flashError(string $message)
    {
        session()->flash('error', $message);
    }
}
```

```
class FlashMessageService
{
    protected $repository;

    public function __construct(SessionFlashMessageRepository $repository){
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function flashSuccess(string $message)
    {
        $this->repository->flashSuccess($message);
    }

    public function flashError(string $message)
    {
        $this->repository->flashError($message);
    }
}
```

And I call them in my controllers like so:

```
    public function store(ContactRequest $request)
    {
        $validatedRequest = $request->validated();
        Contact::create($validatedRequest);
        $this->flashMessageService->flashSuccess('Thank you for getting in touch, someone will get back to you as soon as possible.');
        return Inertia::render('Contact/Index');
    }
```

Here's my layout component:

```
<script setup>
import Navbar from '@/Layouts/Navbar.vue';
import Footer from '@/Layouts/Footer.vue';
import { computed, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

const flash = computed(()=>{
  if(usePage().props.flash.success){
    return{
      type: 'success',
      message: usePage().props.flash.success
    }
  }
  if(usePage().props.flash.error){
    return{
      type: 'error',
      message: usePage().props.flash.error
    }
  }
});


</script >
<template>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
<message-flash-card v-if="flash" :messageType="flash.type" :messageContent="flash.message"></message-flash-card>
        <slot/>
        <Footer></Footer>
</template>
```

And finally, the component itself:

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue';
const props = defineProps({
    messageType: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    messageContent: {
        type: String
    },
    messageAdditional:{
        type: String
    }
});

const classes = computed(() =>
    props.messageType == 'success' ? 'bg-green-200 rounded-xl text-center' : 'bg-red-200 rounded-xl text-center'
);

</script>

<template>
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center m-16">
        <div :class="classes">
            <div class="uppercase text-4xl font-bebas text-center mt-2">
                {{ messageType }}
            </div>
            <div class="sm:max-w-md ml-5 mt-5 mb-5 mr-5">
                {{ messageContent }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

It works great, apart from one small issue. Once I submit the form, the flash component shows as intended. However, if I then navigate to another page it stays there, until I navigate for a second time. I only want the message to stay on the screen until the user changes page. So the flashed data should wipe after the first redirect, however currently it's wiping after the second.

Also, as a side note - I cannot see this data in the developer tools on Firefox. Is this normal?

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check your vue dev tool wether your data still retain old flash message value after navigating to other route?

Comment: @Ali I've just checked and yes it's still there.

Comment: Seems like flash isn’t computed. If could try to make your flash data reactive. I think it would solve the issue.

Comment: @Ali so I got rid of the computed property in my layout and just call the component like so: 

<message-flash-card v-if="$page.props.flash.success" messageType="success" :messageContent="$page.props.flash.success"></message-flash-card>

But same issue.

Comment: Could you try something like.  ‘const {props: $props} = usePage();

const list = ref({ something: true, data: computed(() => $props.value.someProp}));’. It will do the trick for you. I can point you to github discussion if you want to have a detail read on the topic. This code snippet that I posted is from the same discussion actually.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using inertia inbuilt feature

```
class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
{
  public function share(Request $request)
  {
    return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
        'flash' => [
            'message' => fn () => $request->session()->get('message'),
             'otherWhareverMessage => ".......",
        ],
    ]);
  }
}
```

And in front-end

```
<div v-if="$page.props.flash.message" class="alert">
    {{ $page.props.flash.message }}
  </div>
```